# Insert duplicate row in SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I was wondering if it was possible in SQL Server 2008 R2 to create a view with only the last column (DateTime DESC), but this last row should be copied in the view again.

So the end result would be a View with two rows with the same data.

The query to select one row is easy:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Reporting
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Reporting
WHERE DateTime IN (SELECT MAX(DateTime) 
                   FROM Reporting)
```

This returns only one row, but I want to duplicate this row in the view again.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax in the above answer is invalid. You are not allowed to have `ORDER BY` in each data source in the `UNION ALL`. You can have only one at the final statement. So, this is wrong:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

And should be done like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC);
```

I will advice using a different approach. Use fake data source and then `cross apply`.

```
SELECT SI.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) DS ([col])
CROSS APPLY
(

    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC
) SI;
```

You can test easily that the execution plan of this statement is better causing only one ordering and index scan:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try Union all:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Reporting ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of that, thank you. Will accept the answer as soon as I can (have to wait 7 minutes)

Comment: This is not valid syntax.

Comment: gotqn is correct, I recommend his solution, in terms of performance too

Comment: I will have to agree with @gotqn this is not valid syntax to be used in a view. sorry